# Reset button label when the dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using this code to implement copy into clipboard functionality:

```
function copyToClipboard(e, btn) {
  e.preventDefault();     // prevent submit
  var str = document.getElementById("forms-subscribe-email");
  str.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  btn.innerHTML = "Copied!";
  return false;           // prevent submit
}

<div class="modal fade" id="bitcoinModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="offset-top-20 text-md-left">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3>Copy address</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-60 offset-top-35">

          <div class="offset-top-20 text-md-center">
            <form class="rd-mailform form-inline-custom text-left" data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="subscribe" method="post" action="http://.........">
              <div class="form-group form-group-outside">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <label class="form-label form-label-outside text-dark" for="forms-subscribe-email">Bitcoin Address</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="forms-subscribe-email" type="text" name="bitcoin_address" value="3J98t1WpEZ73CNmQviecrnyiWrnqRhWNLy " data-constraints="@Required" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-width-165 btn-primary" onclick="return copyToClipboard(event, this);">Copy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works fine but when I open the dialog second time I see the text button `Copied`. How I can reset the label of the button each time when I open the dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Add this Code On model Show, Need to Reset Text to Orignal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bitcoinModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="offset-top-20 text-md-left">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3>Copy address</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-60 offset-top-35">

          <div class="offset-top-20 text-md-center">
            <form class="rd-mailform form-inline-custom text-left" data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="subscribe" method="post" action="http://.........">
              <div class="form-group form-group-outside">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <label class="form-label form-label-outside text-dark" for="forms-subscribe-email">Bitcoin Address</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="forms-subscribe-email" type="text" name="bitcoin_address" value="3J98t1WpEZ73CNmQviecrnyiWrnqRhWNLy " data-constraints="@Required" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button id="copyBtn" class="btn btn-width-165 btn-primary" onclick="return copyToClipboard(event, this);">Copy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> > 1. Reset Before Open
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("copyBtn").innerHTML = "Copy!";
> ```
>
> > 2. Reset Before Hiding
>
> ```
> $("#bitcoinModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
>     document.getElementById("copyBtn").innerHTML = "Copy!";
> })
> ```

Hope it Helps for Your need.

Comment: this also works. Only different ways to do this solutions.

Comment: How I can reuse this code for 4 dialogs? Is thee some way to create a reusable function?

Comment: Use below function and pass modal and button ids
`function openModal(modalId, btnId){
     $("#"+modalId).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
  document.getElementById(btnId).innerHTML = "Copy!";
 });
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the "reseting" of the text to the closing or hidding event on the modal.

First, modify your `button` with an `id`:

```
<button id="btnCopyToClip" class="btn btn-width-165 btn-primary" onclick="return copyToClipboard(event, this);">Copy</button>
```

Then, in your JS, add the event listener for [`hidden.bs.modal`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) on the modal:

```
$("#bitcoinModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    let btnCopyToClip = document.getElementById("btnCopyToClip");
    btnCopyToClip.innerText = "Copy";
});
```

Comment: It's working, thanks. I have one more question. How I can reuse this code for 4 dialogs? Is thee some way to create a reusable function?

Comment: You would need to change the selector on the function from `#bitcoinModal` to something like `div.modal`. The inside the attached listener check which modal you are "hidding" to clear the button inside that modal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code :

https://jsfiddle.net/aviboy2006/3k7z2c64/1/

Add code in js :

```js
    function openModal(){
      $("#bitcoinModal").modal();
      $('.btn-width-165').html("Copy");
    }
```

Add your open modal code :

```html
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onClick="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```